# Trying to run a rspec test file and it can't find it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to learn RSpec, and thus starting with a simple calculator program.

Confused on how to have the rspec find the file because it keeps saying that it can't load it.

This is the process thus far:

**1**
Calculator class is written and saved as `calculator.rb` file. Create `lib` folder and move the `calculator.rb` file to it.

**2**
In the initial directory (i.e., outside of lib folder), I `rspec --init` which creates `.rspec` file & `rspec/spec_helper.rb` file.

**3**
Then I create write `calculator_spec.rb` file and put it in the `rspec` folder. On top of the `calculator_spec.rb` file, I have this `require 'calculator.rb'`

**4**
I run this command `rspec calculator_spec.rb` to which I get this `'load': cannot load such file`

How do I fix this so the rspec command can find the file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This command would be in the first line of `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../lib/calculator.rb')
```

Comment: ok, pardon my confusion, but is that line needed? I thought with `RSpec`, there's a general command you can run so all tests can get run ... otherwise I have to do that line for every single file?

Comment: plus I ran it right now, while outside of both `lib` and `rspec` files, and again got the cannot load error ...

Comment: By default, `rspec` has no knowledge of your library codebase.  It's conventional for the rspec spec_helper file to load your desired entrypoint.  For codebases that will live in lib for a long time, it's convention for that file to, in turn, require any other file or set of files the library requires.

Rspec *does* have conventions of its own regarding tests.  In general, specs that you write that satisfy the `**/*_spec.rb` regex should be runnable by `rspec` no matter how many specs you write.

Comment: ok, didn't realize that `rspec` has no knowledge of `lib` and `rspec` files. Should I take all the files out of both those folders and run it from parent's directory?

Comment: oh wow. I just took out all those files, and ran this command: `rspec calculator_spec.rb --color` and it worked! But I thought that the "convention" was both `lib` and `spec` folders ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of RSpec you are using but it should create a `spec` directory, not `rspec` in addition to the default `.rspec` file.

@jim-van-fleet's answer should work just fine. However, the best practice is to mirror your code directory under the `spec` directory. So it should look something like this:

[image: rspec hierarchy]

I would also add the following to the top of your `calculator_spec.rb` file

```
require 'spec_helper'

require File.expand_path('../../../lib/calculator', __FILE__)
```